# CSS :hover attribute wrongly working for multiple elements

Tags: html, css

I'm making a color-memory as an exercice, where the player is supposed to hover his/her mouse over a specific position, which then reveals a color code. The code is then supposed to be entered in the correct order by pressing buttons. The only problem is that the color for some reason is revealed when the player hovers the buttons aswell, even though they don't have a :hover attribute in my CSS file. Furthermore, the button move like they're connected to the color square, even though they're not connected there either. Here's a jsfiddle file of my work so far where I've clarified the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/109x7g46/1/ (here's the CSS content):

```
body
{
background-color: #525252;

}
.olle{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 24%;
    transition: background-color 5s ease;
   -webkit-transition: 100s;
    transition: 1s all;   
    transition-delay: 100s; 
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

}
.olle:hover
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 100px;
animation: 125s multicolor;
-webkit-animation: 125s multicolor;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

}
}
@keyframes multicolor {

    1% {
        background: green;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    2% {
        background: yellow;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    3% {
        background: blue;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    4%{
        background: red;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    5%{
        background: cyan;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    6%{
        background: yellow;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    7%{
        background: #525252;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    100%{
        background: #525252;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes multicolor {

    1% {
        background: green;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    2% {
        background: yellow;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    3% {
        background: blue;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    4%{
        background: red;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    5%{
        background: cyan;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    6%{
        background: yellow;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    7%{
        background: #525252;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    100%{background: #525252;
    z-index: 2;
    }
}
input[name='gron']{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 200%;
    z-index: 3;
}
input[name='gul']{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 200%;
    z-index: 3;
}
input[name='bla']{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 200%;
    z-index: 3;
}
input[name='rod']{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 200%;
    z-index: 3;
}
input[name='cyan']{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: cyan;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 200%;
    z-index: 3;
}
input[name='level3']{
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 37%;
    top: 250%;

}
```

My goal is to

**A)** have the square expand and color change **only** when the player hovers the text (not the buttons).

**B)** NOT have the buttons move with the expanding square, but rather have a fixed position (why isn't `position: absolute;` enough for this?).

**C)** preferably only show the color code/change once, but I suppose that's not possible since the button clicks will refresh the page.

I only want to use CSS and HTML for this, so solutions involving JavaScript aren't relevant.

Comment: Your `olle` div isn't closing in your fiddle. This wraps everything under that `div` and so hovering on anything triggers the `hover` animations.

Comment: Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/109x7g46/2/)

Comment: @Chris boy do I feel like an idiot. Thank you so so much, I've been stuck on this for two hours! I was completely positive that the error would be in the CSS file so I didn't even bother checking the HTML. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an unclosed `<div>` in your HTML:

```
<div class="olle"><!-- <-- this is unclosed -->
<div class="olle2"></div>
```

Leaving tags open like that can result in undefined behavior like you're seeing.